# L293D motor shield

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, power, motor, l293d

I have the L293D motor shield on top of my Arduino UNO.

The L293D has a servo attached of 5 volt and a motor of 12 volt there is an external power supply.

If I remove the jumper of the board and power my motor with the 12 volt? Will my servo of 5 volt still have the 5 volt of the Arduino or is this connected to the external 12 volt?

Comment: this cannot be answered without examining the motor shield schematic diagram

Comment: Or at the very least a link to (or even photo of) the shield in question (there is no "The" L293D shield, there's many shields that have that chip on them) so that we have a chance of working out what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

No , your motor will actually get power from outside but the Servo Motor will be powered by arduino even if the jumper removed because the ln298 shield is mounted on the arduino.